# Rotation Animation keyframing

Tags: animation, keyframes

I would like to animate this missile with a rotation animation but starting from frame 600 of my animation and continuing to frame 1500.  I would like the rotation to be a fast one and constant from frame 600 to 1500.

Can it be done?  When I tried it the rotation was slowly advancing from 0degrees to 360 degree from the frame count above.

P.S. I tried also by typing this driver (#frame*0.03) in the y axis but the down side is that it start rotating at frame 0 and did not find a way to keyframe it a frame 600.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: so what rotation is it supposed to do between frame 600 to 1500? do you mean you don't have the result you expect? maybe describe precisely what you want and maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I would like for the missile to rotate (at a constant but 360 fast rotation on the y axis while in flight) starting from frame 617 to 1500.  I am working on a missile launcher animation. The missile launch animation will start at frame 617 to keep going till the end.  File uploaded.

Comment: so from what I see it rotates 360° as it is supposed to, if you want the speed to be constant select the keyframe at frame 616 and press T (Interpolation) > Linear (or in the Dope Sheet > Key > Interpolation Mode > Linear)

Comment: Can I make the rotation faster pls?

Comment: you can move the third keyframe (currently at frame 1500) to the left, or you can type more than 360° at frame 1500 and keyframe again